# how to save changes in terminal

Tags: 12.04, mouse, settings

im trying to configure my mouse speed I set it up to a speed that I like using the terminal but when I restart the pc or shut down it losses all the setting I had input is there a way to save the changes so why work all the time.

ps. ive only used Linux for a couple of days now so the answer may be really obvious and I just dont have a clue

thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by mouse speed? pointer speed or scrolling speed? or do you mean you changed the lines scrolled at once in the terminal? also which command did you use? etc etc

Comment: Do you know what exactly you are are modifying ? i.e., do you create or edit local variables or do you use a GUI interface to configure your mouse ?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and Run this command:

```
xinput --list --short
```

output :

```
abcd@abcd-abcde:~$ xinput --list --short

Virtual core pointer

↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ Logitech USB RECEIVER                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

for me my pointing devices are a Lgitech usb reciver and synaptic touchpad

To list out device Properties :

```
xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

Now reduce it's Property values to suit your need :

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
```

using this command :

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

You may have to play around with this number a bit to set it exactly as you need.

If you need to set this value automatically every time Ubuntu starts then :

create a .sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

change the file to executable :

```
chmod +x
```

and Put this in the start-up applications list.

Thanks To : [vikash-singh](https://askubuntu.com/users/101715/vikash-singh)

Source  : [Configuring Mouse Speed manually](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/)